# How to Implement Trie Delete Function Without Overlapping Error

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie

I'm trying to implement a Trie in c++ in order to solve this problem [https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/706/D](https://stackoverflow.com), and I've gotten everything down except for the delete function. For some reason, even though my code checks to make sure that we don't delete necessary elements, it still does so. I even followed the Digital Ocean trie explanation but that didn't help either. This results in WA for test case #8.

This is my current code, and if you scroll down a bit, you'll find the delete function and its helper methods.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
 
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef pair<ll, ll> pll;
const ll INF = 100000000000;
const ll MOD = 1000000007;
const int MAX_N = 1000005;
 
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
template<typename T> using ordered_set = tree<T, null_type, less<T>, 
rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
 
mt19937_64 rng(chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

typedef struct trie_node trie_node;

char *decimal_binary(int val) {
    char *bin_rep = (char*)(calloc(32, sizeof(char)));
    for(int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(val & (1 << i)) {
            bin_rep[i] = '1';
        } else {
            bin_rep[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    reverse(bin_rep, bin_rep+32);
    return bin_rep;
}

int binary_decimal(char *bs) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 31, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {
        sum += ((int)(bs[i]-'0'))*pow(2, j);
    }
    return sum;
}
 
struct trie_node {
    trie_node *children[2];
    bool is_leaf = false;
};
 
trie_node *make_node() {
    trie_node *node = new trie_node;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        node->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    node->is_leaf = false;
    return node;
}
 
void unload_node(trie_node *node) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if(node->children[i] != NULL) {
            unload_node(node->children[i]);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    free(node);
}
 
trie_node *insert_node(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; bs[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int idx = (int)(bs[i]-'0');
        if(temp->children[idx] == NULL) {
            temp->children[idx] = make_node();
        }
        temp = temp->children[idx];
    }
    temp->is_leaf = true;
    return root;
}

bool check_leaf(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; bs[i]; ++i) {
        int idx = (int)bs[i]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        }
    }
    return temp->is_leaf;
}

int earliest_branch(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    int n = strlen(bs);
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    int last_idx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int idx = bs[i]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx]) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                if(j != idx && temp->children[j] != NULL) {
                    last_idx = i+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        }
    }
    return last_idx;
}

char *longest_prefix(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    if(!bs || bs[0] == '\0') return NULL;
    
    int n = strlen(bs);
    char *lgt_prefix = (char*)(calloc(n+1, sizeof(char)));
    for(int i = 0; bs[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        lgt_prefix[i] = bs[i];
    }
    lgt_prefix[n] = '\0';
    
    int branch_idx = earliest_branch(root, lgt_prefix)-1;
    if(branch_idx >= 0) {
        lgt_prefix[branch_idx] = '\0';
        lgt_prefix = (char*)(realloc(lgt_prefix, (branch_idx+1)*sizeof(char)));
    }
    
    return lgt_prefix;
}

trie_node *delete_node(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    if(!root) return NULL;
    if(!bs || bs[0] == '\0') return root;
    if(!check_leaf(root, bs)) return root;
    
    trie_node *temp = root;
    char *lgt_prefix = longest_prefix(root, bs);
    if(lgt_prefix[0] == '\0') {
        free(lgt_prefix);
        return root;
    }
    int pos;
    for(pos = 0; lgt_prefix[pos] != '\0'; ++pos) {
        int idx = (int)lgt_prefix[pos]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        } else {
            free(lgt_prefix);
            return root;
        }
    }
    int n = strlen(bs);
    for(; pos < n; ++pos) {
        int idx = (int)bs[pos]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx]) {
            trie_node *extra = temp->children[idx];
            temp->children[idx] = NULL;
            unload_node(extra);
        }
    } 
    free(lgt_prefix);
    return root;
}
 
char *search_trie(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    char *res = (char*)(calloc(32, sizeof(char)));
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        res[i] = '0';
    }
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        int idx = (((int)(bs[i]-'0'))+1)%2;
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            res[i] = '1';
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        } else if(temp->children[(idx+1)%2] != NULL){
            temp = temp->children[(idx+1)%2];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    cin.tie(0)->sync_with_stdio(0);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    
    trie_node *root = make_node();
    map<int, int> cnt;
    char *tmpbs = decimal_binary(0);
    root = insert_node(root, tmpbs);
    while(t--) {
        char type; int val;
        cin >> type >> val;
        char *bs = decimal_binary(val);
        if(type == '+') {
            if(cnt[val] == 0) {
                root = insert_node(root, bs);
            }
            ++cnt[val];
        } else if(type == '-') {
            --cnt[val];
            if(cnt[val] == 0) {
                root = delete_node(root, bs);
            }
        } else {
            char *res = search_trie(root, bs);
            int ans = binary_decimal(res);
            cout << ans << "\n";
        }
    }
    unload_node(root);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

UPD 1: Here is a test case where my code fails

```
14
? 1
+ 1
+ 7
? 2
+ 3
? 1
? 6
+ 4
+ 8
- 8
+ 6
+ 6
- 6
? 3
```

My output:

```
1
5
6
7
5
```

Correct output:

```
1
5
6
7
7
```

Comment: I'm very sorry that the code doesn't have comments. Please let me know if you want me to include some.

Comment: `decimal_binary` allocates 32 bytes which doesn't allow space to properly terminate the string. You use `new` to allocate nodes and `free` instead of `delete` to release the memory. None of the memory allocated by `decimal_binary` is ever freed.

Comment: Things not to do : `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, `using namespace std;`  your `typedefs`  the way you define consts (should be constexpr), using types with double underscore prefixes (these are for library/compiler usage).  Using `calloc`...  And not putting all your trie code inside a class (that can safeguard invariants).

Comment: So first learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So basically I should just change all my `free` keywords to `delete`?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks! I'll check out the sources!

Comment: Alr I'll check it out

Comment: @zrli No. If you used `new` to allocate then you must use `delete` to deallocate. If you use `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` then you must use `free`.

Comment: ohh that makes sense. Thanks!