# "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)" In CLion

Tags: segmentation-fault, c++17, clion, trie

While trying to solve a coding problem today, I got tired of OnlineGDB not being able to support large input files, so I decided to pull out CLion and use that instead. However the result that I get is that the exact same code that had worked for me on OnlineGDB get SIGSEGV error in CLion...

My Code(My apologizes for it being so long):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef pair<ll, ll> pll;
const ll INF = 100000000000;
const ll MOD = 1000000007;
const int MAX_N = 1000005;

/*using namespace __gnu_pbds;
template<typename T> using ordered_set = tree<T, null_type, less<T>, 
rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
*/

mt19937_64 rng(chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

typedef struct trie_node trie_node;

char *decimal_binary(int val) {
    char *bin_rep = (char*)(calloc(32, sizeof(char)));
    for(int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(val & (1 << i)) {
            bin_rep[i] = '1';
        } else {
            bin_rep[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    reverse(bin_rep, bin_rep+32);
    return bin_rep;
}

int binary_decimal(char *bs) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 31, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {
        sum += ((int)(bs[i]-'0'))*pow(2, j);
    }
    return sum;
}

struct trie_node {
    trie_node *children[2];
    bool is_leaf = false;
};

trie_node *make_node() {
    trie_node *node = new trie_node;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        node->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    node->is_leaf = false;
    return node;
}

void unload_node(trie_node *node) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if(node->children[i] != NULL) {
            unload_node(node->children[i]);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    free(node);
}

trie_node *insert_node(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; bs[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int idx = (int)(bs[i]-'0');
        if(temp->children[idx] == NULL) {
            temp->children[idx] = make_node();
        }
        temp = temp->children[idx];
    }
    temp->is_leaf = true;
    return root;
}

bool check_leaf(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; bs[i]; ++i) {
        int idx = (int)bs[i]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        }
    }
    return temp->is_leaf;
}

int earliest_branch(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    int n = strlen(bs);
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    int last_idx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int idx = bs[i]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx]) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                if(j != idx && temp->children[j]) {
                    last_idx = i+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        }
    }
    return last_idx;
 }

char *longest_prefix(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    if(!bs || bs[0] == '\0') return NULL;

    int n = strlen(bs);
    char *lgt_prefix = (char*)(calloc(n+1, sizeof(char)));
    for(int i = 0; bs[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        lgt_prefix[i] = bs[i];
    }
    lgt_prefix[n] = '\0';

    int branch_idx = earliest_branch(root, lgt_prefix)-1;
    if(branch_idx >= 0) {
        lgt_prefix[branch_idx] = '\0';
        lgt_prefix = (char*)(realloc(lgt_prefix, (branch_idx+1)*sizeof(char)));
    }

    return lgt_prefix;
}

trie_node *delete_node(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    if(!root) return NULL;
    if(!bs || bs[0] == '\0') return root;
    if(!check_leaf(root, bs)) return root;

    trie_node *temp = root;
    char *lgt_prefix = longest_prefix(root, bs);
    if(lgt_prefix[0] == '\0') {
        free(lgt_prefix);
        return root;
    }
    int pos;
    for(pos = 0; lgt_prefix[pos] != '\0'; ++pos) {
        int idx = (int)lgt_prefix[pos]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        } else {
            free(lgt_prefix);
            return root;
        }
    }
    int n = strlen(bs);
    for(; pos < n; ++pos) {
        int idx = (int)bs[pos]-'0';
        if(temp->children[idx]) {
            trie_node *extra = temp->children[idx];
            temp->children[idx] = NULL;
            unload_node(extra);
        }
    } 
    free(lgt_prefix);
    return root;
}

int search_val(trie_node* root, char* word) {
    // Searches for word in the Trie
    trie_node* temp = root;

    for(int i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        int position = word[i] - '0';
        if(temp->children[position] == NULL) return 0;
        temp = temp->children[position];
    }
    if (temp != NULL && temp->is_leaf == 1) return 1;
    return 0;
}

char *search_trie(trie_node *root, char *bs) {
    char *res = (char*)(calloc(32, sizeof(char)));
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        res[i] = '0';
    }
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        int idx = (((int)(bs[i]-'0'))+1)%2;
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            res[i] = '1';
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        } else if(temp->children[(idx+1)%2] != NULL){
            temp = temp->children[(idx+1)%2];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    cin.tie(0)->sync_with_stdio(0);
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    trie_node *root = make_node();
    map<int, int> cnt;
    char *tmpbs = decimal_binary(0);
    root = insert_node(root, tmpbs);
    while(t--) {
        char type; int val;
        cin >> type >> val;
        char *bs = decimal_binary(val);
        if(type == '+') {
            if(cnt[val] == 0) {
                root = insert_node(root, bs);
                char *tmp = decimal_binary(7);
                cout << type << " " << val << " find 7: " << search_val(root, tmp) << "\n";
            }
            ++cnt[val];
        } else if(type == '-') {
            --cnt[val];
            if(cnt[val] == 0) {
                root = delete_node(root, bs);
                char *tmp = decimal_binary(7);
                cout << type << " " << val << " find 7: " << search_val(root, tmp) << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            char *res = search_trie(root, bs);
            int ans = binary_decimal(res);
            cout << ans << "\n";
            char *tmp = decimal_binary(7);
            cout << type << " " << val << " find 7: " << search_val(root, tmp) << "\n";
            free(res);
        }
    }
    unload_node(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Given Input:

[image: Input]

OnlineGDB Result(Works):
[image: As you see, it passes]

CLion Result(SIGSEGV):
[image: Why???]

I tried going online and searching for what might've caused this error, but nothing showed up looked quite like what I was trying to find. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong please? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) All those type-aliases. Using C allocations functions like `calloc`. `cin.tie(0)->sync_with_stdio(0);` `#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>` when you have e.g. `std::map`. Explicit C-style casting. Using the old C-macro `NULL`. Pointers for strings instead of `std::string`. And a *lot* more.

Comment: As for the crash itself: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Well in my defense, I do competitive programming, and all competitive programmers such as Benq use things like ```cin.tie(0)->sync_with_stdio(0);```

Comment: If you just copy-paste stuff without knowing its meaning, or even if it's really needed (that part is *not* needed), then you're part of a [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is a bad thing. So-called "competitive" programming is ***not*** a way to learn the basics of programming or any programming languages. All it seems to "teach" are bad code, bad habits, and way too often even *invalid* code.

Comment: Actually I do know what I'm doing when I use FastIO. Just saying....

Comment: And please, instead of criticizing my code, help me answer my question instead. :pray:

Comment: To write a good, clean, maintainable and *working* program, start with an empty piece of paper. Write down all the requirements, all the limitations, and then do a thorough analysis of the requirements and limitations. From that analysis do a design. Use drawings to draw things like lists and trees, try to make all the operations "work" using only pencil and paper. Don't implement anything until you're certain it works using pencil and paper.

Comment: Once your paper implementation works, you should start with an *empty* `main` function and ***nothing*** more. Build with extra warning enabled (treated as errors), and only when it builds cleanly test it in all possible ways. When it passes the tests, add one or two lines, perhaps three, but not more. Build and test again. Do this over and over again. *When* you get a problem, it's easy to isolate it, perhaps even creating a [mre] just to debug it by itself. Don't continue until again the code builds cleanly and passes all tests.

Comment: Lastly about things that seems to work on one system, but not on another: That's a clear indicator of your code having [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is a problem with a pointer, not pointing to where you expect it to point. By using the above techniques to writing your program, it should be very easy to debug and fix.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why it works on the online compiler. Please only post solutions and stop posting not as related issues in the comments. In fact I've already tried your ideas such as drawing it out and I did start with an empty main function.

Comment: And a possible hint about the crash: C-style strings (using `char*` pointers) are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. You create a lot of strings that are *not* null-terminated. Which means all your string functions using those strings will go *out of bounds* and lead to the above mentioned *undefined behavior*. If you use `std::string` for all your string, you won't have that problem. A good books is really worth its weight in gold for learning proper C++. Competition-sites and 99% of all youtube videos are not.

Comment: This seems to have all of the same issues your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321113/how-to-implement-trie-delete-function-without-overlapping-error). You don't allocate space for a terminator in `decimal_binary` and you're mixing `new` and `free`.

Comment: If the input was text instead of an image then others could run the code and show you where it crashes, but all of that has been explained to you before to no avail and you seem hostile to those who might want to help so I fear you may be on your own with this one.

Comment: Oh I thought it was cause of something else.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a function to convert from decimal to a binary string, I changed it to a `bitset` and then used `bitset.to_string()`. This meant that I also changed `char*` to `string`. Not only that, I saved over 40 lines of code by changing my delete function to be recursive. I ended up with this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef pair<ll, ll> pll;
const ll INF = 100000000000;
const ll MOD = 1000000007;
const int MAX_N = 1000005;

using namespace __gnu_pbds;
template<typename T> using ordered_set = tree<T, null_type, less<T>, 
rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;

mt19937_64 rng(chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

typedef struct trie_node trie_node;

int binary_decimal(string &bs) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 31, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {
        sum += ((int)(bs[i]-'0'))*pow(2, j);
    }
    return sum;
}

struct trie_node {
    trie_node *children[2];
    bool is_leaf = false;
};

trie_node *make_node() {
    trie_node *node = new trie_node;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        node->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    node->is_leaf = false;
    return node;
}

void unload_node(trie_node *node) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if(node->children[i] != NULL) {
            unload_node(node->children[i]);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    free(node);
}

trie_node *insert_node(trie_node *root, string &bs) {
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; bs[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int idx = (int)(bs[i]-'0');
        if(temp->children[idx] == NULL) {
            temp->children[idx] = make_node();
        }
        temp = temp->children[idx];
    }
    temp->is_leaf = true;
    return root;
}

bool check_leaf(trie_node *root) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if(root->children[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

trie_node *delete_node(trie_node *root, string &bs, int depth = 0) {
    if(!root) return NULL;
    if(depth == sizeof(bs)) {
        if(root->is_leaf) {
            root->is_leaf = false;
        }
        if(check_leaf(root)) {
            delete(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
        return root;
    }

    int idx = (int)bs[depth]-'0';
    root->children[idx] = delete_node(root->children[idx], bs, depth+1);
    if(check_leaf(root) && root->is_leaf == false) {
        delete(root);
        root = NULL;
    }

    return root;
}

string search_trie(trie_node *root, string &bs) {
    string res = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    trie_node *temp = root;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        int idx = (((int)(bs[i]-'0'))+1)%2;
        if(temp->children[idx] != NULL) {
            res[i] = '1';
            temp = temp->children[idx];
        } else if(temp->children[(idx+1)%2] != NULL){
            temp = temp->children[(idx+1)%2];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    cin.tie(0)->sync_with_stdio(0);
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    trie_node *root = make_node();
    map<int, int> cnt;
    string tmpbs = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    root = insert_node(root, tmpbs);
    while(t--) {
        char type; int val;
        cin >> type >> val;
        bitset<32> bset(val);
        string bs = bset.to_string();
        if(type == '+') {
            if(cnt[val] == 0) {
                root = insert_node(root, bs);
            }
            ++cnt[val];
        } else if(type == '-') {
            --cnt[val];
            if(cnt[val] == 0) {
                root = delete_node(root, bs);
            }
        } else {
            string res = search_trie(root, bs);
            int ans = binary_decimal(res);
            cout << ans << "\n";
        }
    }
    unload_node(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `trie_node *node = new trie_node;` and `free(node);` is still a very real problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do I need a terminator? Is it to remove un-needed memory? Or... Could you explain why? It would be very helpful.

Comment: You need to terminate the string with a 0 so you can tell where the end is. In your original code `for(int i = 0; bs[i] != '\0'; ++i)` would happily run right off the end of the 32 characters you allocated into undefined behavior land. Same with `for(int i = 0; bs[i]; ++i) {`, `int n = strlen(bs);`, and everywhere else you expect there to be a zero at the end.

Comment: But that's not a 0... it's a NULL character... Am I right or wrong?

Comment: It is a 0, or a `NUL` character. https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html